# Photoshop CC 2018 - Text Size (on cavas live preview) missing

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, font-size

This happened recently. I’m not sure which update caused it.

In the past, we’ve been able to manually increase/decrease text size using the arrow keys in Photoshop.
You would be able to see the text on the screen increase/decrease in size as well.

Right now, you only see the size change **after** you submit your value and hit enter. You no longer can live preview...

Any idea what’s going on?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug of the last release. Adobe knows about this bug:

https://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/photoshop-19-0-1-character-palette-adjustments-via-inputs-not-behaving-as-expected